# how to get all item with specific value from dict?

Tags: python

Lets say we have a dict `{'a':1,'b':0,'c':1,'d':0}`, how can we get all the keys with value 0? I tried using for loop to check each items' value and return the key into a list but it totally make no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension over the items of the dictionary, filtering for the value you're looking for:

```
def keys_of_value(d, value):
    return [key for key, val in d.items() if val == value]
```

Usage:

```
>>> keys_of_value({'a':1,'b':0,'c':1,'d':0}, 0)
['b', 'd']
```

Note that this requires you to iterate through all the items in the dictionary. If you need to do this very often, you might want to construct a reverse-lookup dictionary, which maps values to lists of all keys with that value:

```
def reverse_dict(d):
    res = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        res.setdefault(val, []).append(key)
    return res
```

Usage:

```
>>> rev = reverse_dict({'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1, 'd': 0})
>>> rev
{0: ['b', 'd'], 1: ['a', 'c']}
>>> rev[0]
['b', 'd']
>>> rev[1]
['a', 'c']
>>> rev[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 2
```

Now the reverse-lookup is just as fast as the forward-lookup, though you have to construct the reverse-lookup dictionary first.